# The given path's format is not supported error exception while accessing Helixbase project

Tags: helix, gulp

Has anyone faced this issue, while installing the Helixbase for Sitecore 9 update 1? The builds are successful with no errors. Publishing all projects task with gulp also works fine. but still I am facing this issue.

[image]

Comment: What is your "sourceFolder"?

Comment: D: projects helixbase

Comment: The root of you source control is at the root of your D drive? What is this setting set to in your environment? https://github.com/muso31/Helixbase/blob/master/src/Project/Helixbase/code/App_Config/Include/Project/z.Helixbase.DevSettings.config#L3

Comment: Z.helixbase is pointing to correct directory as well

Comment: is there a backslash at the end?  if so, remove it.

Comment: I used Helixbase for the Sitecore Hackathon this past weekend with Sitecore 9.0.1 and didn't have an issue.  Could you include a copy of the configuration.  Specifically z.Helixbase.DevSettings.config and gulp-config.js file?

Comment: I cleared the configuration and rerun the setup for it. And it resolved. 1 thing I would like to share that you should be using administrator powerd cmd or VS. Also the targetrootfolder was having a demo with it

Answer (score 2):

Before you proceed with setting up Helixbase or Habitat solution, make sure your sitecore instance is working fine and you have followed all the steps given in installation guide.

Yesterday I have installed Sitecore 9.0.1 update 1 and setup Helixbase solution from github on top of it which is working fine.

Your error seems to be related to paths you have specified. Please check following configuration files, I have provided some details of attributes which should correct according to your setup.

**z.Helixbase.DevSettings.config**

- sourceFolder: Provide the path of your source code location
- rootHostName: Provide correct hostname, if your sitecore instance has hostname other than the default one i-e 'helixbase'.

**Helixbase.config**

- targetHostName: In the site configuration tag, make sure to remove *'demo.'* from targetHostName="demo.$(rootHostName)" attribute only if your site is not hosted with subdomain as 'demo'.

Once the above configurations are correct then run the gulp tasks and make sure that you get the status as 'Process terminated with code 0.' which means task ran without any issue.

If you have followed above correctlty then your helixbase should work without any issue.